# Checkboxes in PDF forms don't show up in OS X

Tags: hyperref, mac, forms

I'm trying to create a PDF form using hyperref. The form looks fine, except for the checkboxes. In both Adobe Reader and Preview.app, the boxes do not appear. My cursor changes if I mouse over where the box is, and if I click on it I can even see the briefest flicker of the box and checkmark. Both promptly disappear.

In Adobe Reader on Windows, the checkboxes are initially invisible, but show up the first time I click on them. In FoxIt Reader they work exactly as expected.

Here is a minimum working example, which I copied from a tutorial:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[left=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=10mm,right=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[
  xetex,a4paper=true,colorlinks=true,
  pdftitle={Key form},pdfsubject={Key},
  pdfauthor={ich},pdfpagemode=UseNone,pdfstartview=FitH,
  pagebackref,pdfhighlight={/N}
]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section*{Request for a key}
\begin{Form}
Front door: \CheckBox[name=ht]{}\\
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

And here is a link to the output: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2126832/ex0001.pdf

I am using XeTeX, but I tried compiling with PDFTeX and encountered the same issue. I recently upgraded to OS X 10.7 (Lion) and Texlive 2011.

I've spent a lot of time googling this issue and have found no mention of it elsewhere. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Just in case it helps in diagnosing the issue, I should note that the checkboxes in the [eforms manual](http://carroll.aset.psu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex/doc/eformman.pdf) work just fine. (I also tried using eforms, without any luck. No surprise, since eforms uses hyperref.)

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: The checkbox appears in your sample document and in my version of this document I compiled it. It appears correctly in both Preview and Adobe Reader. I'm running 10.6.8, so maybe this is a Lion-specific problem.

Comment: The check box works in Adobe Acrobat Pro.  I am running 10.6.8 as well.

Comment: Your example pdf shows no checkboxes with AR9 on Linux, but the same document compiled on Linux with TL2011 does, so I assume it's a Mac issue.

Comment: Your pdf  document does not work on my Lion system, neither with Preview nor with Acrobat Pro. If I try to compile the pdf using TeXLive 2011 and LuaLaTeX it doesn't work either. It seems to be Lion specific, but while compiling the document.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help troubleshooting this. It sounds like it is something that happens during compilation on Lion and only manifests itself in certain viewers--Adobe Reader on Linux and Windows and Adobe Reader and Preview.app on OS X 10.7. Does anyone have any idea why only a Lion-installed TL2011 would generate these broken checkboxes?

Comment: @mike I don't think we've established that it's a TL problem as opposed to a Lion problem.  Since your sample document (compiled with TL 2011 on Lion) displays correctly for me using 10.6.8, I *don't* think this is a completely a TL problem.

Comment: @AlanMunn I don't think that this is necessarily a TL2011 bug--just that whatever's going on only manifests in documents that are compiled on Lion-installed TL2011 and viewed in certain PDF viewers (note that the checkboxes also do not appear in Adobe Reader for Linux and Windows). This suggests to me that somehow TL2011 behaves differently on Lion. Or at least that the files themselves are defective in some way; it isn't purely an issue with the software used to view them.

Comment: Among the statements on Adobe compatibility issues with Lion, the closest to your issue is the following.  "For Acrobat customers who utilize functionality like forms, digital signatures, portfolios, guides, 3D, extended PDF documents and rights management, and who require the Acrobat plug-in to render PDF documents in the Safari browser, Adobe recommends that you continue to use Safari 5.0.x and Mac OS X 10.6. Adobe will provide updates as we continue to investigate this issue." See also: http://techland.time.com/2011/07/22/adobe-os-x-lion-is-buggy-adobe-reader-not-compatible/

Comment: Like @AlanMunn, I too run MacTeX2011 under MacOSX 10.6.8; similarly, I experience no problems of the variety described by the OP. More on my setup: The front end can be either TeXShop or TeXworks; the previewer can be one of the built-in previewers that come with these packages, Preview.app launched externally, or Acrobat 10.1.1.

Comment: I am having a similar issue after upgrading to OSX Lion. My hyperlink boxes are invisible in the output PDFs now.

Comment: @MichaelS I converted your answer into a comment to the question, as it's not a real answer.

Comment: Same problem here. I'm running Lion 10.8.2 and Skim PDF viewer 1.4.2. The boxes appear with Adobe Reader 10.1.5, but I don't like it because there is no inverse search. I can make the links visible using the option colorlinks=true, but this spoils print quality (for my printer, at least).

Comment: Oh, when then paper was compiled by ArXiv the problem disappeared!

Answer (score 3):

I prepared two pdf documents with a further simplified input file

```
\documentclass{article}
%\pdfminorversion=1
\usepackage[unicode=true, verbose]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Request for a key}
\begin{Form}
Test: \CheckBox{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

One document I prepared with a 10.6 computer, one with 10.7, both with TL2011 and LuaLaTex. The output files look identical to the eye if opened in a text editor. I used `diff -a lion.pdf snow.pdf` to show further details and got

```
218,219c218,219
< /CreationDate (D:20111027072803+02'00')
< /ModDate (D:20111027072803+02'00')
---
> /CreationDate (D:20111027091652+02'00')
> /ModDate (D:20111027091652+02'00')
250c250
< /ID [<1E45A68F3C173651B121446FAD778EB3> <1E45A68F3C173651B121446FAD778EB3>]
---
> /ID [<0CCBB711863F46770F8A748517E79A96> <0CCBB711863F46770F8A748517E79A96>]
```

So the files are virtually identical.

Please note that even the file prepared on Snow Leopard and TL2011 does not show the form with Adobe Acrobat Pro 9 on Snow Leopard. Preview is fine on the same computer.

I would conclude, that either

1. TL does not and did not prepare proper pdf files and that bug got
   somehow visible now
2. The pdf viewers do not display the pdf files
   properly, this is more likely, but not limited to Lion.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. Thank you for the detective work. Can you tell me whether the Snow Leopard–compiled PDF displays properly in Lion’s Preview.app?

Comment: The Snow Leopard–compiled PDF does not display properly in Lion’s Preview.app.

Comment: That is helpful. Given @MartinSchröder's comment above, I thought there was something wrong with the file itself. I guess it could be a display issue that is shared by Adobe Reader for Linux and Windows, but one would hope that Adobe's software would implement its own spec correctly. The strange thing is that Martin said that the same document displayed fine in AR for Linux when he compiled it himself with TL2011 on Linux. Maybe someone else could confirm this?

Comment: Your file does _not_ work with TL2011, Linux and AR9. But changing `\CheckBox{}` to `\CheckBox[name=foo]{}` makes it work. Looks like a bug of `hyperref` to me.

Comment: Maybe Martin should make that an answer. It actually helps what to do and makes the solution easier to find.

Comment: Now that *is* interesting. I will try this tonight and report back.

Comment: Alas, Martin's solution didn't fix the issue for me. An interesting discovery in its own right, though. It looks like this is a legitimate bug in hyperref. Per the hyperref README, I emailed Heiko Oberdiek and submitted a bug report to the tracker at https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?group=hyperref

Comment: @mike I am wildly guessing but this might be a Javascript rendering problem. Can you identify if the document compatibility options are the same? Back in the day, when I was  living in a cave, we used to design web pages with such and Javascript is very picky about the missing fields of dynamic elements. Martin might have hit the spot (as usual) in this sense.

Comment: @mike as a followup I have edited the PDF in the Acrobat directly and placed another checkbox (I am on windows btw) and the manually placed one works seamlessly whereas the old one still becomes invisible when clicked. And when the properties are checked both looks identical indeed.

Comment: @percusse Thank you for checking on that. I remain stumped and it looks like there has been no activity on the hyperref bug tracker. The package maintainers issue updates pretty frequently, though, so I remain hopeful that they will get to the bottom of this soon.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a genuine bug in hyperref; the key tipoff for me is that if I run the pdf through `pdf2ps`, I get

```
   **** Error: Required entry /BBox not present in Form.
               Output may be incorrect.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: Stream object is missing the stream data.
```

and if I convert the ps back to a pdf with `ps2pdf`, there is no checkbox.

Interestingly, when I open the pdf in Adobe Reader, it asks me if I want to save changes on closing it (even though I've made no changes).  If I do that, then the checkbox appears fine everywhere, and round-tripping through a `.ps` file preserves the checkbox.

I've reported this as https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/153